# ASP.NET: Import JSON file in DB in server explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I have created a ASP.NET MVC project. I have made the controller and model. Now I want to import a JSON file into my local database.

Is this possible and how?

My model:

```
public class Adres
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public float Latitude { get; set; }
    public float Longitude { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

JSON example:

```
[{"SubmissionId":1,"Date":"2014-07-15 17:53:02.127","Latitude":52.385,"Longitude":4.636,"Address":"AH Kruisstraat 10, Haarlem "},
{"SubmissionId":2,"Date":"2014-07-15 15:46:19.627","Latitude":52.382,"Longitude":4.857,"Address":"AH: Bos en Lommerweg 117, Amsterdam,"}]
```

Comment: How is the data being sent to the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example which sends JSON data to the controller using jQuery and uses classic ADO.NET with a stored procedure to insert the record into a database:

**Controller:**

```
public class Adres
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public float Latitude { get; set; }
    public float Longitude { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult JsonExample()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveToDatabase(Adres adres)
    {
        adres.Date = DateTime.Now;

        string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using(var command = new SqlCommand("InsertAdres",connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date",adres.Date);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Latitude",adres.Latitude);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Longitude",adres.Longitude);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address",adres.Address);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            connection.Close();
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "JsonExample";
}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnSaveJson").click(function () {

            var adres = {
                Id: 1,
                Latitude: 155.77,
                Longitude: 245.99,
                Address: $("#txtAddress").val()
            };

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/SaveToDatabase',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Saved to database, notify user...");
                },
                data: adres
            });
        });
    })
</script>
<input type="text" id="txtAddress" value="221B Baker street" />
<input type="button" value="Save Json To Database" id="btnSaveJson" />
```